# Accessing private blob images from Azure Storage in app

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an ASP.NET Core API that is accessed by an iOS app in a multi-tenant environment. Each tenant is assigned a storage container.

The app has a few points for image uploading, which need displayed in the app, for instance, a customer profile picture.

My blobs are not public so I need to find the best approach for returning these images in the API for the app to consume.

I've thought of a few approaches here.

<strike>1. When an image is uploaded, generate a non-expiring SAS and store it in the database. I quickly realized this wasn't the right approach. If I regenerate the keys, these URLs become invalid. So we can scratch this one off the list.</strike>

2. When a tenant calls GET /customers, where these urls would be included in the returned response, generate a short lived SAS on the container level and send it along with the header. The app could then append the SAS when it's going to display the image. This is what I'm leaning towards.
3. Have my API download each blob and send the base64 along in the response. This seems heavy handed and unnecessary.
4. Expose my own API endpoint to generate a SaS on demand for a particular blob/container and have the app call it first.

Is there another hopefully better approach I haven't considered here? I think #2 is probably the way to go.

Thanks!

Comment: I would also go with #2 (or #4 as a fallback option).

Comment: The way 2 may be a better way. Besides, you also can try to change the container access level and set the access level to blob. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to set the blob access level because while the profile picture is fine, there is also a driver's license image that gets stored which is obviously more sensitive.

Comment: @Nate, like Gaurav Mantri(storage experts) said, the #2 should be the better one. Please post an answer for the issue, and it would be helpful for others who has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to hit #2 and include a short lived SAS in response header from API that can be used to append to the URLs which are otherwise not public.